# JavaScript jQuery fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a problem with fancybox. I read a few answers here, but had't found a solution for my problem. I have these scripts loaded in my webpage:

Sripts for fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Other scripts that my page includes:

```
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.plugins.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/selectnav/selectnav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/tweet/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/fitvids/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/isotope/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/sharrre/jquery.sharrre-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/template.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/customizer.js"></script>
```

Problem is that when I have all of these fancy box won't work. I tryed many combinations and found that the only possible for a fancbox to work is to remove script 'jquery-1.8.3.min.js' from page. If I remove it dropdown menu is not working, and the fancybox does.

Where is the problem? I just copied scripts, not a body code, because I toought it's not nessesary.

Comment: what is jquery.plugins.min.js contain?

Comment: did you load jquery as the first script? the other scripts look like they require jquery to be loaded as the first script.

Comment: It should have Jquery first and then load other script files.